# How to use json object as return type of do in background asynchronous task android?

Tags: android, json

I am working with android.I had created an app in which json data is loaded in asynchronous task and do something in the onpost execute method. I used the following code

```
public class Feat extends Activity {


JSONArray user = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> t = new AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>()
     {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

             try {
 HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("MY URL");

                    HttpResponse response2 = httpclient2.execute(httppost2); 
                    HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                    is = entity2.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success2222 ");

            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());


                }
                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb2.append(line + "\n");

                        }
                        is.close();

                        result2=sb2.toString();
                        res=result2.substring(3);
                        Log.i("result",""+res);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());


                }
                try
                {
                     jArray2 = new JSONArray(result2);

       Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray2.length());
                    final String imgArray[] = new String[jArray2.length()];
                    String name[] = new String[jArray2.length()];

                      for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++){


                        JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
                         imgArray[i] = json_data2.getString("track_url");
                         name[i] = json_data2.getString("campaign_name");

 }  }

                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                }   






                return jArray2;
        }


          @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

               setContentView(R.layout.ss);
               t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cat1);

}


     };
     t.execute(); 




}
```

Now how can i use return type of do in background in post execute method ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read json inside postexecute() like this

```
public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("images");
                 image_first =new String[json.getJSONArray("images").length()];  //initializtion
                  image_second =new String[json.getJSONArray("images").length()];

                for(int i=0;i<json.getJSONArray("images").length()/2;i++){

                image_first[i] = (articles.getJSONObject(i).optString("image_first"));
                }
                for(int j=json.getJSONArray("images").length()/2;j<json.getJSONArray("images").length();j++){

                    image_second[j]= (articles.getJSONObject(j).optString("image_second"));



                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the class I have used:

```
public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... arg0) {
                   //All the try, catch etc.
                   //be sure to end it with 
                   return (yourJSONObject)
                   }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

                   //Your code
                   }
```